# How to use Node.js with Jemalloc?

Tags: node.js, jemalloc

Node.js can be used with Jemalloc (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21973). In most cases it would shorten RSS and this is my huge problem.

But I can't find any info about how to use node with Jemalloc, nor on a machine, nor in docker.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: I think it's done by patching node's source code or messing with the build files

Answer (score 8):

I just went through the process of switching our nodejs app to jemalloc, here is how I did it on Debian stretch:

**Install jemalloc:**

```
sudo apt-get install libjemalloc-dev
```

**Find the jemalloc binary:**

```
sudo find / -name "*jemalloc*"
```

Look for a file in a folder like /usr/lib/... ending with .so, for example path could be */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so*

**Configure server to use jemalloc for all programs:**

1. Create file with preloading config:

`sudo nano /etc/ld.so.preload`

2. Add the path to the jemalloc binary to the file:

`/path/to/jemalloc/binary`

3. Restart nodejs and check if jemalloc is used, e.g. like this (if jemalloc is used you should see some lines showing the jemalloc binary):

`cat /proc/<PID OF NODEJS>/smaps | grep jemalloc`

**Alternative: Use jemalloc only for nodejs**

In bash execute

`export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/path/to/jemalloc/binary`

before starting the nodejs process

Comment: Thank you! I'll try soon. But does this mean that jemalloc will become a system-wide memory allocator?

Comment: Actually yes. In case you do not want that you could do:

export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:<path to jemalloc binary>

before starting the nodejs process. However this requires to do it each time before nodejs starts. There are probably options to only configure it for the nodejs binary but I am not aware of those right now...

Comment: On Amazon Linux 2 I'm getting <jemalloc>: Error in munmap(): Invalid argument after starting a nodejs process

Comment: Hi Vincent, could be the specific setup of OS on Amazon's Linux 2. The procedure is tested on Debian Stretch. In the meantime I have this running on a couple of Ubuntu 20.04 servers as well as some Debian Buster hosts. So I assume it should work for most not too old Debian derivatives.

Comment: Hi @Tyreal, do u mean the `/path/to/jemalloc/binary` in `export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/path/to/jemalloc/binary` to be something like `/usr/bin/jemalloc.sh` and not something like `/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so`?

Comment: @SonNguyen no, it needs to be the file ending with `.so` which was installed by the apt repo.